# AS3 > Access of undefined property loader

Tags: actionscript-3, loader

I think I have al the imports required to display this image however I'm getting this error:

```
1120: Access of undefined property slideImage.
1120: Access of undefined property loader.
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild.
1120: Access of undefined property loader.
```

My action script is inside a class named play.as

This is the AS3 code:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;


    public class play extends MovieClip {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.load(new URLRequest("img/Layer_1.jpg"));
        addChild(loader);


        public function play() {
            // constructor code
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is that the entire AS code?  You need to look into the first error in that list, relating to a call to an undeclared property called `slideImage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code'd be enough:

```
package  {    
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;


    public class play extends MovieClip {
        private var loader:Loader = new Loader();

        public function play() {
           loader.load(new URLRequest("img/Layer_1.jpg"));
            addChild(loader);
        }
    }
}
```